# Provide Alloy with a "pool" of custom Strings

Tags: alloy

I'm interested in using the String type of Alloy, (especially due to the fact it allows the use of special character). 
I noticed that in order to add a given String to an instance, it is sufficient to include it in an expression. e.g.

```
fact stringInsert{
   none!="a"+"b"+"c"
}
```

will lead to the creation of atoms "a","b" and "c" in any generated instances.

Now my question is, is there a way to declare a pool of strings,defining all possible string atoms that might occur in satisfiable instances, BUT whose number respect the scope given and can be further constrained ?

As an example, if we consider the above fact as declaring a pool of string atom {"a","b","c"}, I would like instances obtained from the execution of a model using this pool with a global scope of 2  to only contain two of those three strings "a","b", and "c".

Comment: I guess this feature is not supported, but I ask just in case. :-)

Comment: So the individual concrete strings in the pool are treated as if they were declared using `lone sig` *something-or-other* `extends String` ?  (At first I thought "any individual will have to be declared `one`, but `lone` would allow the scope limits you want.)

Comment: The thing is that you cannot extend the String signature. 
Moreover if you would like to have the string ":" , how would you put : in a signature declaration ?

Comment: Yes, point taken.  Hence the phrase "as if" declared that way ...

Comment: i misread your comment, my bad, yes exactly "as if" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only declare an **exact** scope for `String`, e.g.,

```
run {} for 3 but exactly 5 String
```

It is currently not possible to only give an upper bound for Strings, e.g., `for 5 String`, and ask Alloy to find a solution (with respect to other constraints) with up to 5 strings.  So if you try to set the scope for `String` to 2 in your example above, you will still get all 3 string literals declared in your model ("a", "b", "c"), which is consistent with string literals being "one sigs" extending the abstract `String` sig; if on the other hand you set the scope to 5, Alloy will generate 2 additional string atoms, "String$0" and "String$1".

Comment: That's what I "feared".